# Logically inferred from the given statements?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Consider the following statements relating to the level of poker play of four players $P, Q, R$ and $S$.

$I. P$ always beats $Q$

$II. R$ always beats $S$

$III$. $S$ loses to $P$ only sometimes

$IV. R$ always loses to $Q$

Which of the following can be logically inferred from the above statements?

$(i)$ $P$ is likely to beat all the three other players

$(ii)$ $S$ is the absolute worst player in the set

1. $(i)$ only
2. $(ii)$ only
3. $(i)$ and $(ii)$
4. neither $(i)$ nor $(ii)$

---

My attempt :

$P→Q→R→S$, and $P↔S$, So, only statement $(i)$ is true always. But $S$ *may not be absolute worst player in the set*, since $S$ can beat $P$ sometime.

Therefore, option $(1)$ is true. But I've given option $(3)$ in exam.

> Can you explain in formal way, please?

Comment: See ques-8, at page no.-2 http://www.gate.iisc.ernet.in/GATE2016questions/S5_CS.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is probably 4. You simply can't infer that $P$ always beats $R$, despite the fact that $P$ always beats $Q$ and $Q$ always beats $R$ - take for example the sissors-rock-paper game where sissors beats paper and paper beats rock, but still rock beats sissors.

The assumption they're would have to make is that the level defines an order which means that we could infer that since $P>Q$ and $Q>R$ that $P>R$, but that assumption is questionable since we would have $P>Q>R>S$, but still $S$ seem to win over $P$ sometimes.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for nice explanation.